# Securing a Rest API to be used in conjunction with a desktop app

Tags: java, spring, rest, security, http

I am currently building a REST API using Spring boot. Currently the API will be delivering JSON data to a JavaFX application, in the future the API will possibly be accessed by an Angular app. Its probably also worth noting that it will not be possible for users to create new users, that responsibility will be with the sysadmin. I am wondering about authentication in this type of API.

The general idea is that there will be only one level of authorization, which will give the user access to all of the data from the system. I am wondering how should I implement this authorization. Most of the solutions that I have looked into (Spring security, OAuth etc.) seem like they won't work since the client side application won't be run in a browser.

Currently, I am passing the users details from the client side with every request, and checking them against the hash of the password shown in the database.

So my question is, how to I secure an application that won't be run in a browser, and as such does not have access to cookies, http sessions etc.

Comment: "...seem like they won't work since the client side application won't be run in a browser." - Why do you think this? OAuth or any of these could be used in a full application. You just need to implement the client side. Any client will have access to the Cookies, etc. A simple encrypted cookie mechanism or OAuth will suit your needs.

Comment: Spring Security works with non-web or non-browser applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless if the client is a desktop app, mobile app, or web app, The same principals can apply to authentication of RESTful APIs.

Usually, a token can be stored client side and used until it expires, if any (and thus needs to be refreshed). You can then include the token in the Authorization header as a bearer token with each API call completely removing Cookies from the picture.

A lot of folks like using JWT's which is just a JSON Structure that is base64 encoded and then signed to prevent tampering. JWT's make it easy to be free from a persistence layer and truly build a distributed authentication framework without relying on Redis or some other Key/Value Store. The only thing needed is the secret or private key. One of the downsides with JWT's used in this style though is it's harder to blacklist tokens since they are valid until they expire. The tokens themselves will probably be larger than an opaque token also.

Depending on what technology you use, you would check that the token is signed or lookup the user/session info server side.